# How to set video.js src in c# code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, html5-video, video.js

I am attempting to use video.js in a project.  If I use the following video tag, it will work as expected.

```
<video id="videoTag" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls="controls"
    preload="auto" width="640" height="264" poster="null"
    data-setup="{}" runat="server">
       <source src="http://cite1.nwmissouri.edu/NWCloudTest/convertedVideos/
        424a909969434ae392c8ec7563fcbac8.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
</video>
```

However, if I attempt to set the source dynamically in my C# code, the video player just spins and plays no video.  If I look at the source for the webpage it shows the correct source in the video tag.

Here is the C# code:

```
videoTag.Attributes["src"] = "http://cite1.nwmissouri.edu/NWCloudTest/convertedVideos/424a909969434ae392c8ec7563fcbac8.mp4";
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Deos your videoTag represent <video/> or <source/>. "src" is an attribute on <source/> and not <video/>

Comment: The above is how I managed to get it to work with a standard html5 video tag.  I also tried giving the <source/> an id and runat="server" and changing its src attribute directly and that did not work either.

Comment: Can you post the html that is generated by your C# code to help you debug this issue further?

Comment: The html generated is identical.  When I set the source for the video in C# the html code is the same as the hard coded version above.

Comment: You should not need the `<source/>` element. Remove it(just have the `src` and `type` be attributes of `<video/>` and set your video tag to `autoplay`, that should do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get rid of the `<source/>` element. Once you have, set the `type` and `src` attributes of the `</video>` tag(with their respective values that you were setting in the `<source/>` tag). Also, make sure that your video tag is set to `autoplay`.